# Cant connect Angular 7 to Spring Boot - no request body sent

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, http, http-headers

I have this method:

```
public getUniversityIdFromName(request): Promise<number> {
   return this.http.post<number>(this._dbUrl + 'university/findByName', request, this.httpOptions).toPromise();
}
```

where `http` is an instance of `HttpClient`.

For whatever reason, even though this request works on Postman, I cannot reproduce with my Angular client. I suspect it has to do with headers, but I have tried setting content type and it doesn't seem to help. I'm using the following method:

```
public httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
};
```

Here are images of Postman and the network tab in Chrome:

[image: postman request and response]

[image: postman headers]

[image: network tab, chrome]

Comment: You're showing the pre-flight OPTIONS request, is your server correctly configured to handle CORS?

Comment: Oh, no I don't think I did anything to add that! Guessing that's the issue then?

Comment: I don't know, it's just a guess. The preflight request isn't supposed to have a body, though, so that's not the problem in itself. Have you looked at the server logs?

Comment: Seems like the pre-flight is the only request that is sending. I guess that would suggest that the request is getting killed preflight, so I'll add CORS and see if that helps.

Also, error is: 
```Required request body is missing: public int com.RSOhub.hub.api.UniversityController.findByName(com.RSOhub.hub.dto.FindUniversityByNameRequest)]```

Comment: Yes, it definitely won't send the actual POST unless the OPTIONS succeeds.

Comment: you can see if its CORS issue in chrome on console tab with XMLhttprequest cannot load message.

Comment: It was CORS! Adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` as a decorator to my API post solved the issue! Thanks so much!

Comment: May I ask which Spring Boot version you are using? I had the problem since the version 2.2.x. This change causes the problem in my case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22496. I had to remove the Origin-Header in the OPTIONS pre-flight request to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this below code, it should work

```
getExample() {     

const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders()

.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)

.set( 'Content-Type','application/json' ) }     

return this.Http.get("url/examplpeAPI" + 'getData' , options)   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was CORS - Adding @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") as a decorator to my API functions in the controllers solved the issue